# Phonegap - ajax request doesn't work

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, rss

Have tried for hours to create an simple rss reader with phonegap but it doesn't seems to work. Have tried to set access to: `<access origin="*"/>` but that does not work.

Here is the code I use to get the rss feed:

```
$.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent("http://array.se/feed/"),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.responseData.feed);

      $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(key, value){
        var thehtml = '<a href="'+value.link+'"><li>'+value.title+'</li></a>';
        $("#factsfeed").append(thehtml);
      });
    }
  });
```

The code works in the browser but when I try it out on my Android it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the dataType to 'jsonp'

Also, "document.location.protocol" might not work as the protocol in PhoneGap is file://, you can probably just remove that and append http to the string after it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, replacing the "document.location.protocol" with "http" did the trick!